# MediaPlayer change DataSource Error when MediaPlayer complets Playing First Audio

Tags: media-player, android-mediaplayer, mpmediaplayercontroller

Any one Help for MediaPlayer Error.
when aim is to Change DataSource and Play second Audio when First Audio is Compliting its Playing.

My Code is below :- 
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {

```
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
        {

           String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + FILENAME+arrListSize+".wav";
           mMediaPlayer.release();
           mMediaPlayer = null;
           mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           Uri uri  = Uri.parse("file://"+fileName);                                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try 
            {
              mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
              mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {                       
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Error :- setDataSource called in state 32

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it looks like the previous instance of the `MediaPlayer` is not released completely. When the playback has completed, the player is in **Paused** state when the `onCompletionListener` is invoked. Can you please `stop` the `MediaPlayer` before releasing the same?

```
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.release();
mMediaPlayer = NULL;
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
...
```