# Error(-19,0) Mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make an app that plays specific sounds on button click , I got like 100 buttons created statically not in an array or anything , and I assigned the sounds to each button correctly the problem is , after playing a number of buttons it gives me that error my questions are

1. Any way I could possibly switch to generic code from this mess
2. Anyway I could stop getting this error and the sounds to continue working on every button whatever the amount of sounds played??

Below is my code :

```
   package com.example.buttonsdemo;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       Button messageButton_0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.akali);
       final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick_0= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.akali) ;
       messageButton_0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

              mpButtonClick_0.start();
              if(!mpButtonClick_0.isPlaying()){
                 mpButtonClick_0.stop();
                 mpButtonClick_0.release();
              }

     }  
});
```

And it goes on like this for 100 more buttons or so any help plz

```
Logcat:
03-04 16:21:21.925: E/MediaPlayer(5769): error (-19, 0)
03-04 16:21:21.925: E/MediaPlayer(5769): stop called in state 0
03-04 16:21:21.925: E/MediaPlayer(5769): error (-38, 0)
03-04 16:21:22.067: W/MediaPlayer(5769): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-04 16:21:22.067: W/MediaPlayer(5769): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-04 16:21:22.115: D/AndroidRuntime(5769): Shutting down VM
03-04 16:21:22.115: W/dalvikvm(5769): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769): java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1025)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at com.example.buttonsdemo.MainActivity$39.onClick(MainActivity.java:766)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 16:21:22.145: E/AndroidRuntime(5769):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You probably need to add the logcat to see exactly what kind of error you're getting

Comment: Just added the logcat

Comment: Error -19 should be `NO_INIT` if I'm not mistaken. That could happen e.g. if the MediaPlayer fails to create the underlying AudioTrack, if setDataSource fails or if you call certain methods prior to initializing the MediaPlayer.

Comment: so you suggest that I try to play X number of buttons but don't overlap them ??

Answer (score 6):

From the error messages, it is clear that a `start` on `MediaPlayer` is called when the same is in error state. From your messages,

```
03-04 16:21:21.925: E/MediaPlayer(5769): stop called in state 0
```

State 0 corresponds to `MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR`

```
03-04 16:21:21.925: E/MediaPlayer(5769): error (-38, 0)
```

The error no. -38 corresponds to `INVALID_OPERATION` from `MediaPlayer::start`. Please note that `INVALID_OPERATION` is set to `-ENOSYS` which is **-38** from `errno.h`.

You may have to investigate why your `MediaPlayer` is in an erroneous state.

Comment: I believe because it does not delete the created file after playing is done and I have no idea how to do that , I tried with the .release() and .stop(), .reset() and still nothing , because I guess they are in the onclick method

Comment: When the file playback is complete, you would receive an `onCompletionListener` callback in which you could invoke a `stop` and `release` to release the `MediaPlayer`, after which you can create a new instance of the player.

Comment: @KarimBibars you really should take a look at the StateDiagram(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram). The flow of the MediaPlayer isn't as simple as you think it is.

Comment: can u give me an example on how to use the oncompletionlistner on that pervious code ??

Comment: You could refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152172/mediaplayer-change-datasource-error-when-mediaplayer-complets-playing-first-audi

Comment: ok I checked it and now i see the missing part is putting the mediaplayer as null and when i do that i get that error
The final local variable mpButtonClick_0 cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: @KarimBibars In your code, do you feel that the creation of the `MediaPlayer` could be performed inside the `setOnClickListener` or maybe even inside `onClick` method?

Comment: Is there any variable defined for this number **-38** ?
for e.g. **public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED = -1007**

Comment: -38 is `ENOSYS` as captured in my original comment which is coming from a standard file `errno.h`

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the documentation of [MediaPlayer.start](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start%28%29) and [the State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram).

You probably are calling the MediPlayer while it's in one of the invalid states ({Idle, Initialized, Stopped, Error}), which would cause the exception.