# Playing sounds on button click doesn't start

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-event

I am trying to make an app that plays sound when button clicks and I have like 100+ sounds and 100+ buttons. I have created the buttons and now am mapping it to the sounds to be played. Another thing, when clicking more than "x" number of times the `mediaplayer` crashes. Any ideas on how to fix that??

Note: The code does not want to execute as it is right now, and I really don't understand why.

```
package com.example.buttonsdemo;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Creating Sound arrays
    int i = 0;
    MediaPlayer[] mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer[120];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int z = 0; z < 121; z++) {
            mediaplayer[z] = null;
        }

        // Creating Button Array
        Button button[] = new Button[120];
        for (int x = 0; x < 121; x++) {
            button[x] = null;
            button[x].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // Creating Media player array

        mediaplayer[1] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alistar);
        mediaplayer[0] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.akali);

        button[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.akali:
                    i = 0;
                    break;
                case R.id.alistar:
                    i = 1;
                    break;
                }
                mediaplayer[i].start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.buttonsdemo/com.example.buttonsdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=120; index=120
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=120; index=120
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.example.buttonsdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-05 01:10:34.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the array. But you're missing an initialization for its contents.

in your loop you need to put

```
button[x]= new Button(this);
button[x].setOnClickListener(this);
```

You also are using the variable `i` before you initialized it.

But now that I think about it, what you actually need to do is brush up on your `MediaPlayer` documentation. You really don't need (nor want) to have an array with 120 MediaPlayer objects. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29):

> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.

Your newest version has several errors. First error:

```
for (int z = 0; z < 121; z++) {
        mediaplayer[z] = null;
    }
```

Since your array has 120 elements, your condition needs to be

```
 for (int z = 0; z < 120; z++) {
        mediaplayer[z] = null;
    }
```

Second mistake: you're setting the button array elements to null and then you try to access them

```
for(int x=0;x<120;x++){
   button[x]=new Button(this);
   button[x].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: and you should really mark your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205855/error-19-0-mediaplayer) as answered...

Comment: Could you post the changed code, and the changed logcat please?