# Cannot play video from server in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have to play video from php server in android by using url. So I used the below code. But its not working. I don't know the mistake which I had done.

```
VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
String Video="http://xxx/android/deepcut.mp4";
video.setMediaController(mediaController);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Video));
video.start();
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What is the reason to close the question ?

Comment: i have not closed the question.

Comment: I know its not you. I am asking the user who vote to close this question.

Comment: i dont know why it is??

Comment: anyway do you know the answer for it??

Comment: What error you getting post your logcat here

Comment: @Biraj MediaPlayer  error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: @Biraj MediaPlayer Error (-38,0)

Comment: @Divya, that error shows that your video format is not supported by the device you are using. Are you executing the project in emulator ?

Comment: One more question Is internet permission is given in manifest.xml fiel?

Comment: @Divya did you declare **Internet** and **Access Network State** permissions in **Manfiest**?

Comment: You problem has a solution on SO refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482018/mediaplayer-error-38-0

Comment: @Awais,@Biraj i have given internet permission

Comment: @Kedarnath i have checked in device also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-38 refers to ENOSYS error code from errno.h (see this explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206308/768935)

You seem to try to start the playing before the preparation is complete. Use the `setOnPreparedListener()` method to set a preparation listener and call the start() method only after the preparation is complete.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mp.start();
  }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

And remove the current `video.start()` invocation from the code.

Took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482018/mediaplayer-error-38-0)

Credits goes to [him](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768935/allprog)

Comment: you will not get an onPerpared callback until you call start().  MediaPlayer has a prepare/prepareAsync() call, but VideoView does not.  In VideoView, prepare happens as part of start().

Comment: correction: prepare() happens as part of setVideoURI().  Nonetheless, you do not have to wait for calling start() until onPrepared().  You can call start() directly after setVideoURI().

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
String urlStr = "http://videos.com/link/to/video.mp4";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlStr);

VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vv.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {return false;}
});
try {vv.setVideoURI(uri);} catch (Exception e) {}
try {vv.start();} catch (Exception e) {}
vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(null);
    }
});
```

add these permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Sorry cannot play this video error! MediaPlayer Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: did you change current link to your video link??

Comment: Yes i have changed my url link. But its not working.

Comment: hmmmm, it should be decoder problem or something, because it works fine with my video links... :/

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Try any library, like FFMPEG for Android

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially correct.  The *only* permission needed to play a video from the internet is internet permission.  You can do this by adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in your manifest (inside the   section)

What's also probable is that you are trying to play a video that is not supported by your device, e.g. playing a main/extended/high profile, or a level 5 AVC video, or even HEVC.  You can run avprobe/ffprobe on your file to get the profile and codec info for it.